# python django celery systemd

Tags: python, django, celery, systemd

I'm trying to build an NGINX/Gunicorn/Celery/RabbitMQ/Django server for several services.I am failed to do demonetization for celery.

**My project directory below where celery is installed in virtualenv:**

home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/fanvault

**My configuration file below in /etc/conf.d/celery**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

CELERY_BIN="home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="fanvault"

CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

**My celery.service in etc/systemd/system/**

```
[unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/fanvault/fanvault/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/python3.5 -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES}  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/python3.5 -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES}  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/python3.5 -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES}  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My celery.py file in home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/fanvault/fanvault**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from fanvault.settings import DEBUG

if DEBUG is True:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "fanvault.local_settings")
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "fanvault.aws_settings")

app = Celery('fanvault')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.beat_schedule = {

    'pull_movie_home': {
        'task': 'movies.tasks.pull_movie_explore',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=3)
    }

}

app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
```

**when I do "sudo service celery start" getting following error:**

Job for celery.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status celery.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**When I do "sudo journalctl -xe" getting following:**

```
-- Unit celery.service has begun starting up.
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 python3.5[23368]:   File "<string>", line 1
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 python3.5[23368]:     home/ubuntu/fanvault/bin/celery multi start w1 w2 w3  -A fanvault --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid  --
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 python3.5[23368]:                                         ^
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 python3.5[23368]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 systemd[1]: celery.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 sudo[23337]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 06 12:00:11 ip-172-31-53-174 systemd[1]: Failed to start celery.service.
-- Subject: Unit celery.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are passing the Celery startup commands to Python3 in your service file. Those are shell commands, to be executed directly.

Comment: in which line in my celery.service

Comment: ExecStart/Stop/Reload

Comment: I followed http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#service-file-celery-service

Comment: which is the best practice to run my celery service though I exit my ubuntu server, celeryd, systemd, celerybeat ?

Comment: No you didn't. That doc has those lines being passed to /bin/sh. You're passing them to Python3.

Comment: bro Daniel can you please tell me where to change exactly to get running my celery service even when I exit my ubuntu server?

Comment: I don't understand what else to tell you. Change those lines so that they don't call python3 but bin/sh, exactly as in the doc you've linked to.